# What is the reason for the existing of two data structures of pose with frame and time in ROS?

Tags: ros, posestamped

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the reason for the existing of two data structures of pose with frame and time in ROS: **geometry_msgs::PoseStamped** and **tf::Stamped<tf::Pose>**?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/309156/what-is-the-reason-for-the-existing-of-two-data-structures-of-pose-with-frame-and-time-in-ros?/) by [abrzozowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/28240/abrzozowski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 290 on 2018-11-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-11-22**:
One is a message used to store and transmit data so is compatible with message passing subsystem, serialisation, etc. The other is designed for processing information within ROS so includes methods to perform geometric operations.

**Comment by [abrzozowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/28240/abrzozowski/) on 2018-11-22**:
I know that it's current architecture design of the whole ROS. But you don't think, should it be made uniform (exists one of them)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The reason for this separation is that it's actually recommended to keep your business logic separated from the ROS integration. If we start importing ROS domain concepts and data structures into all sorts of code, that code will be "glued" to ROS 1 (or 2). That is undesirable.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [abrzozowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/28240/abrzozowski/) on 2018-11-23**:
@gvdhoorn I see. Well, that explains it. Thanks.